# Maxwells Equations in a curvilinear coordinate system

Tags: physics, tensors

I was wondering if anyone would be able to explain to me how the author goes from equation 3 to equations 4(a,b,c) in [this paper](http://www.opticsinfobase.org/view_article.cfm?gotourl=http://www.opticsinfobase.org/DirectPDFAccess/04272EAD-0D76-C864-55C516AE46E2E0DC_18904/josaa-13-11-2247.pdf?da=1&id=18904&seq=0&mobile=no&org=University%20of%20Rochester).

I am confused how to treat the contravariant metric tensor in these equations.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the metric tensor in wrong coordinates initially? That is, are you suspecting that the tensor $g^{ij}$ is at first in the $x,y,z$ basis, and needs to be transformed to the $u,v,w$ basis?

Comment: I do not think so.  I need to use the tensor given in eq 2, which is in the u,v,w basis.  I just do not see how to multiply out the tensor, given that it is a 3x3, when Hj is a scalar

Comment: I was not interpreting $H_j$ as a scalar, for instance, $H_j\equiv(H_u,H_v,H_w)^T$. Is this right?

Comment: For instance, isn't the Einstein/tensor summation convention $g^{ij}H_j=\sum_j g^{ij}H_j$?

Comment: The math seems to work if that is how you look at it.  I do not understand why that works.  This is probably where I am confused

Comment: Would the Hj vector be the covariant component?

Comment: I think that $H_j$ is covariant can simply be noted by the position of index being lower. But my training in this is not extensive.

Comment: That makes sense.  Do you have any idea where equation 4a comes from.  If I treat Hj as the vector you say, what is Hk?

Comment: Note that the order of variables in cycle is $vuz$ (equation (1)). In equation 4a, the author is considering $j=z$ (implicit in $E_j,E_z$), and in the $ijk$ cycle, we are using cycle $uzv$, so $i=u$ and $k=v$.

Comment: I do not quite understand.  I get what you are saying about cycling, but if that is the case, does the metric tensor $g^{ij}$ change?

Comment: Turns out the reason lies in the definition of E and H.  They come from an electromagnetic tensor that he never introduces in the paper.  Probably more of a physics question.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you "need" physics here. Rather, physics "needs" math. I think the only assumption is TE polarization. That is, that the electric field is transverse to the motion, which mathematically means the tensor $E_j$ is simply $(0,0,E_z)$. I write the equations here for convenience.

$$e^{ijk}\partial_jH_k=-ik_0\mu\sqrt gg^{ij}E_j.$$

You were wondering about equation 4a, so I will try to show how that is found.

First note that 
$$g^{ij}E_j=g^{iv}E_v+g^{iu}E_u+g^{iz}E_z=0+0+g^{iz}E_z=g^{iz}E_z.$$
This is a contravariant 1-tensor (in the super script $i$).

So, both sides of the equation are 1-tensors in $i$. Let us consider the $i=z$ component. On the left side, we consider

$e^{zjk}\partial_jH_k=\partial_vH_u-\partial_uH_v$, and we are done. That is, equation 4a is

$$\partial_vH_u-\partial_uH_v=-ik_0\mu E_z.$$

I would encourage you to try to make sure you can derive equation 4a yourself. This will require you to develop some more comfort with the notation. Then try tackling the other two equations. Note that for instance on the left side of the Maxwell's equations, we are holding $i$ fixed and summing over all $j$ and $k$. This is the Einstein notation. See here for instance: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_summation

Note that another component of the above equations, say for $i=v$, we have

$$e^{vuz}\partial_uH_z+e^{vzu}\partial_zH_u=\partial_uH_z-\partial_zH_u=0.$$